# R Shiny - Incorrect cex value - uploading text file, wordcloud package

Tags: r, shiny

I just started learning Shiny and I am trying to do a simple project as a way to get a feeling of how it is as a dev tool.

My goal : to do a wordcloud app. Input: a .txt file. Output: a wordcloud.

I am getting a "incorrect cex value" error, and my guess is that my file isn't uploading properly... Am I correct? If so, what would be an equivalent to read.csv for a text file? I have gathered that it is read.table, but I am apparently wrong since I am getting an error using read.table

Here is my code, vastly adapted from [WordCloud](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/word-cloud.html) :

*** global.r ***

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)

# Using "memoise" to automatically cache the results
getTermMatrix <- function(text) {
    # Careful not to let just any name slip in here; a
    # malicious user could manipulate this value.

    myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords,
    c(stopwords("SMART"), "thy", "thou", "thee", "the", "and", "but"))

    myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
    control = list(minWordLength = 1))

    m = as.matrix(myDTM)

    sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
}
```

**server.r**

```
function(input, output, session) {
    # Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix

    my_data <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$files
        if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
        data <- read.table(inFile, header=T, sep="\t", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
        data
    })

    terms <- reactive({
        # Change when the "update" button is pressed...

        input$update
        # ...but not for anything else
        isolate({
            withProgress({
                setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
                getTermMatrix(input$inFile)
            })
        })
    })

    # Make the wordcloud drawing predictable during a session
    wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        v <- terms()
        wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
        min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
        colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
    })
}
```

**ui.r**

```
fluidPage(
# Application title
titlePanel("Word Cloud"),

sidebarLayout(
# Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
sidebarPanel(
#######
fileInput("selection", "Choose a text:"),


#
actionButton("update", "Change"),
hr(),
sliderInput("freq",
"Minimum Frequency:",
min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
sliderInput("max",
"Maximum Number of Words:",
min = 1,  max = 300,  value = 100)
),

# Show Word Cloud
mainPanel(
plotOutput("plot")
)
)
)
```

**SAMPLE INPUT FILE **

As requested. You may use this .txt (it's Shakespeare) : http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2242/pg2242.txt

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file ?

Comment: Yes : ) http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2242/pg2242.txt

Comment: @abourbaki Use the `debug()` function to assist in analysis of code: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/debug.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes/edits to be done to get your app working! The way you are handling the file input is completely wrong :). You can directly put `input$selection` in the `getTermMatrix()` function and then read the file contents in `global.R`. Have a look at [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html) to understand how to upload a file and read its contents in Shiny.

The error was because there was no file read and as a result, there was no data to be fed into `Corpus()` function. In the following code, as there was no file input when you start the app, an error was displaying that no file is read. But, after uploading a file, the error disappears and the corpus is shown. To not display the error, I included a small `tags()` in ui.R. May be you can find a better get around for that.

Have a look at the following working code and try to extend it to your future purposes.

**`ui.R`**

```
shinyUI(
fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Word Cloud"),
  tags$style(type="text/css",
             ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
             ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
  ),

  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      #######
      fileInput("selection", "Choose a text:"),



      actionButton("update", "Change"),
      hr(),
      sliderInput("freq",
                  "Minimum Frequency:",
                  min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
      sliderInput("max",
                  "Maximum Number of Words:",
                  min = 1,  max = 300,  value = 100)
    ),

    # Show Word Cloud
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
)
```

**`server.R`**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix

  terms <- reactive({
    # Change when the "update" button is pressed...

    input$update

    # ...but not for anything else
    isolate({
      withProgress({
        setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
        getTermMatrix(input$selection)
      })
    })
  })

  # Make the wordcloud drawing predictable during a session
  wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    v <- terms()
    wordcloud_rep(names(v), v, scale=c(4,0.5),
                  min.freq = input$freq, max.words=input$max,
                  colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  })
})
```

**`global.R`**

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)

# Using "memoise" to automatically cache the results
getTermMatrix <- function(f) {
  # Careful not to let just any name slip in here; a
  # malicious user could manipulate this value.

  text <- readLines(f$datapath,encoding = "UTF-8")

  myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))

  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords,
                    c(stopwords("SMART"), "thy", "thou", "thee", "the", "and", "but"))

  myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
                             control = list(minWordLength = 1,wordLengths=c(0,Inf)))

  m = as.matrix(myDTM)

  sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
}
```